# How do I get a list of locked users in an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, system-administration, locked

I want to be able to list all of the users in a given database along with an icon that determines whether they are locked or not. The problem I'm having is querying the "locked" status for a given user, I though it might have been on `all_users` but it isn't. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Found it!

```
SELECT username, 
       account_status
  FROM dba_users;
```

Answer (score 36):

```
select username,
       account_status 
  from dba_users 
 where lock_date is not null;
```

This will actually give you the list of locked users.

Answer (score 2):

This suits the requirement:

```
select username, account_status, EXPIRY_DATE from dba_users where 
username='<username>';
```

Output:

```
USERNAME        ACCOUNT_STATUS                   EXPIRY_DA
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYSTEM          EXPIRED                          13-NOV-17
```